# iPhone - UIActivityIndicatorView does not hide when stopped

Tags: iphone, hide, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a custom UIWebView written like this :

## .h

```
@interface MiniWebViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString* destinationURL;

    UIWebView* webView;
    UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicatorView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* destinationURL;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView* webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicatorView;

- (void) run;

@end
```

## .m

```
@synthesize destinationURL;
@synthesize webView;
@synthesize activityIndicatorView;

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"MiniWebView" bundle:nil]) {
        self.destinationURL = @"";

        self.view.frame = frame;
        self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.webView.center;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) run {
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.destinationURL]]];
}
```

It is called an initied from another ViewController :

```
- (void) aFunction {
    MiniWebViewController* oneViewController = [[MiniWebViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(/*Some Rect*/];
            oneViewController.webView.tag = i;
            oneViewController.destinationURL = /*SomeURL*/;
            oneViewController.webView.delegate = self;

            [self.view addSubview:oneViewController.view]; /* the Web view is inside this one */
            [oneViewController run];
    }

    - (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        int webViewID = webView.tag;
        MiniWebViewController* webViewController = [self.webViews objectAtIndex:webViewID];
        [webViewController.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    }

    - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        int webViewID = webView.tag;
        MiniWebViewController* webViewController = [self.webViews objectAtIndex:webViewID];
        [webViewController.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
    }
```

Into IB hidesWhenStopped is also checked. Everything is linked. The style of the indicator is set to "Large White" into IB.

When running, the indicator is not large, but small.
It is successfully started and stopped (delegate calls are triggered), but it doesn't hide when stopped.

What's the problem ? I don't see...

Comment: If you're using Xcode 3.x, did you save your XIB?  Is it properly connected to your view controller?  Put a `Log` statement in to test to make sure your indicator is not nil. `NSLog(@"indicatar nil:%i", activityIndicatorView == nil);`

Comment: @Wayne Hartman : It is not nil, and of course, yes, the XIB is saved. FYI I'm running XCode 4. For the momenbt, I hide it manually. But I wonder why it does not look large, and why it does not hide when stopped...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Stupid I am, and XCode/cocoa really doesn't help.

I had loaded a wrong XIB name that **DOES NOT** exist.
So I ask to load something that does not exist, and the app stil works, even showing and using objects that does not exist. Untill one call does not work as expected. No crash...
It's nonsense.

Answer (score 6):

After a careful look in your code, you are modifying the UIActivityView in your `init` method.  Change those so that they are in your `viewDidLoad`.  At init, you view is not yet loaded, therefore, there is not an instance of those objects yet created in your controller.

These are the statement that need to be moved:

```
self.activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

self.view.frame = frame;
self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.webView.center;
```

This goes back to a fundamental of Objective-C:  Sending a message to a `nil` object...returns `nil`.  This is an annoying feature at times because there is no compile time warning, nor is there any runtime exception--a *feature* of the language.

Comment: You're perhaps right, but frame and activity indicator center are correctly set when called from there. And the first line is here only for test purpose, as this property is already set into IB. I could remove it, it wouldn't change anything. Even if moved into viewDidLoad.

Comment: Error : when moved into viewDidLoad, self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.webView.center does not work anymore.

Comment: I removed self.activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = YES from the class. I's still set into IB. Problem is still there and I don't think it could be caused by a wrong placement of the frame init.

Comment: Are you able to hide the activity manually: `[self.activityIndicatorView setHidden:YES];`

Comment: Yes. That's the reason why I don't understand why it does autohide.